# Use non Microsoft account for signing up on TFS

Tags: tfs

I just signed up on TFS for a free account and now I want to invite a colleage in my company. I want to invite him using his company email instead of his microsoft email account. How can I do that? I tried to add him using his company account but when he gets an email for joining the TFS, the login page only allows to use Microsoft account.

Comment: Which one are you using? TFS on-premises or  VS Team Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description with a free account(Microsoft Account).I'm wondering if you are using VSTS. TFS on-premises will use the domain account to login in TFS, not Microsoft Account.

If you want to login VSTS with your company account.

> ***Sign up for Visual Studio Team Services with a work or school account***
>
> Control access to Visual Studio Team Services the same way you do with
>   Microsoft services like Office 365 and Azure. When you sign up with a
>   work or school account, your Visual Studio Team Services account is
>   connected to your organization's directory (tenant) in [Azure Active
>   Directory (Azure AD).](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/) You can then use the same username and password
>   as other Microsoft services, like @fabrikam.com. Azure AD helps you
>   enforce policies around accessing your team's critical resources and
>   key assets.

More details, please refer link from MSDN: [Sign up for Visual Studio Team Services: Git & Agile for DevOps, continuous integration, & continuous delivery](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/sign-up-for-visual-studio-team-services#orgaccount)

Comment: I tried to sign up using my company account but when I input my company email it says `We couldn't find an account with that email address. Enter a different email address or get a new Microsoft account`

Comment: @WasimQadir Just as the link said, If you want to sign up using your company account,  **your Visual Studio Team Services account  need to organization's directory (tenant) in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).**  Your account should like  xx@xxx.com **. Azure AD** .Otherwise, you have to use Microsoft account.